# Is there any way to embed youtube shorts vertically in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, embed

I am embedding a youtube shorts video in my WordPress site. I copied the embedded link by right clicking on shorts video and got the embed code.

In WordPress, I used a text block and simply copied that  code. In the WordPress admin, the video is shown vertically while in the front end it is horizontal (just like youtube watch videos).

Is there any way to resolve this? Can I embed the shorts vertically on my site?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the current embed code you're using I'll have to take a guess.  If it looks something like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxVideo_IDxx?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
```

Simply swap the width and height so that it becomes:

```
<iframe width="315" height="560" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxVideo_IDxx?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
```

This works for me as of today.

If this is a foolishly simplistic answer to a deeper question that I'm misunderstanding please forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

I have added custom class and then give css for specific height,width to that class with the '!important' property.

Also, remove the default height, width from the . Surprisingly, it worked.